# Photoshop History - save with psd?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, script, history

When I work on an Photoshop document, I do many changes, create snapshots, and so on. But after saving the psd and open it, the history is empty. I didn´t find anything. I can log the history to txt with detailed parameters, but they won´t restore and this log ins a global logger for photoshop, not for documents. And actions will display only with a single part of log file (also in detailed recording in preferences). In the history I will see all steps the action will do.

So it´s not possible to save the log with psd as a sidecar? I can do layer comps or save the snapshots in separate files. But what, if I work on a retouching and make a break till next day? Or the photoshop app crash?

Any scripting for log recording and read these steps? Like a livetracker.